# sub queries error

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am unable to find the error in the below sql sub queries. I want PublisherWise ImgCount as my output. Kindly guide me where i did mistake. TIA.

```
SELECT pubinfo.mf_pu_id,pubinfo.mf_pu_name, lang.mf_li_name, COUNT(innQ1.mf_cr_fileid) AS Imgcount 
FROM  mf_publication_info AS pubinfo 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT mf_cr_fileid,mf_cr_masid,mf_cr_pubid, innQ.`mf_mi_publisheddate`                                          
     FROM mf_compare_results  
     WHERE mf_cr_enginedecision='p'AND mf_cr_userdecision IN('M',' M',' EM','EM')
     INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT mf_mi_id,mf_mi_publisheddate 
          FROM mf_media_info  
          WHERE mf_mi_publisheddate BETWEEN '2015-07-27' AND 
              '2015-07-31' AND `mf_mi_processid`=16
         ) AS innQ
     ) AS innQ1  
      ON innQ1.mf_cr_fileid=innQ.mf_mi_id
      ON pubinfo.mf_pu_id=innQ1.mf_cr_pubid
      INNER JOIN mf_language_info lang
          ON pubinfo.mf_pu_langid = lang.mf_li_id
          GROUP BY pubinfo.mf_pu_name ORDER BY pubinfo.mf_pu_name
```

Comment: Did you end the first sub-query properly? (A bit unclear what you're trying to do.)

Comment: yes the first sub-query is ended. I want publisherWise ImgCount with publishedDates. The "mf_mi_publisheddate" field is in table mf_media_info. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Which dbms? (Several errors according to ANSI SQL...)

Comment: i am using mySQL as my dbms

Comment: Thanks jarlh!! could you please enlight where i did the mistake

Comment: WHERE should be at end of a JOIN chain. Single ON for each JOIN. Also the general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is open to the following two interpretations, (I think), please can you correct me if i'm wrong.

Example 1:

```
SELECT x
FROM table 1
    LEFT JOIN (sub 1) alias ON x=x
    INNER JOIN (sub 2) alias ON x=x
    INNER JOIN table 2 ON x=x
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY x
```

Example 2:

```
SELECT x
FROM table 1
    LEFT JOIN (
        (sub 1) alias
        INNER JOIN
        (sub 2) alias ON x=x
    ) alias ON x=x
    INNER JOIN table 2 ON x=x
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY x
```

If it is the second one (which is what makes sense to me), then you need an alias for your first subquery and an open bracket at the first left join and ON criteria for the first inner join subquery.

Please write as I have a very much simplified version of what you are trying to write, it should make more sense this way.